# How to change firefox plugin search bar background color?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have simple firefox search addon where my search query hit the server and render webpage. I want to change the background color of search bar on search. I did google but did not find any results. Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a little more what exactly you need help with? And could you post your code or a link to it? Do you simply want to know how to change the color, or do you need help catching the "on search" event too? Is this simply an extra search engine for the search bar, or is it a custom search bar?

Comment: Background image can definitely be done (though I don't know how) -- see http://userstyles.org/styles/12471/search-bar-custom-background-image